# Changing the default source of linked picture

Tags: excel

I'm making a a dashboard and I've linked a picture so I can scroll between my various support groups and the charts live update, this works fine.  The problem is I'm trying to add a year selection Combo Box so I can show various years.  I can't seem to make the Combo Box's link. What I have currently:

[image: what i have currently]

What I require:

[image: what i require]

Is this even possible in Excel?

I'm not sure if you can change the fixed image that I have linked by the first box.

Comment: I believe what your asking for is called "cascading drop down lists" to make one dependent upon another... Yes, it can be done.  Try searching with those terms.

Comment: Yes I was searching that as most of the net points to these.  Unfortunately it doesn't really help me with my situation as I'm trying to change the default image that I picture linked in my first box.  Any other thoughts would really help.

Comment: Try this link http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1440-excel-create-interactive-charts.html